# Oracle Account Not Responding

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have an Oracle instance which has user1, user2 and user3 accounts. Yesterday I was able to log in to all three accounts. Today, I can get in to user1 and user3, but user2 is completely 'frozen' in some way that I don't understand.

If I try to log in to user2 with sqlplus it just spins forever. It does not connect, does not time out, nothing happens until I press CTRL+C to kill the process. Connecting as user1 or user3 is instantaneous.

I thought I would try locking user2 out and then try unlocking it. The query to lock the user ran for 25 minutes before I gave up! Locking user1 then unlocking user1 ran instantly.

Using [TOAD](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/) and connecting as a DBA, I used Session Browser to investigate. I found 11 connections to the database as user2. Five of these appear to be my failed attempts at connecting using sqlplus. None of these connections are showing any open cursors, a current statement or any locks. On the waits tab 10 of the connections show a "row cache lock" with:

- seconds in wait between 3,000 and 60,000
- P1 = 7
- P1 Text = "cache id"
- P2 = 0
- P2 Text = "mode"
- P3 = 3
- P3 Text = "request"

One of the connections stands out as it appears to be very old. It shows a "SQL*Net message from client" with:

- seconds in wait > 600,000
- P1 = 1413697536
- P1 Text = "driver id"
- P2 = 1
- P2 Text = "#bytes"
- P3 = 0
- P3 Text = ""

I am not able to kill any of these 11 sessions. After I issue the kill command (using TOAD, with or without immediate option) it runs for 45-60 seconds then says "Session is marked for kill." but the session never goes away.

Any ideas what this means or how I can kill these sessions and restore access to the user2 account?

**Update**: There were some interesting lines in the alert log:

> Tue Dec 29 09:37:45 2009
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>   Tue Dec 29 10:25:45 2009
>   `>>> WAITED TOO LONG FOR A ROW CACHE ENQUEUE LOCK! pid=17
>
>   System State dumped to trace file [snip]\udump\ora_1988.trc
>
>   Tue Dec 29 10:54:17 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Tue Dec 29 10:55:47 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Tue Dec 29 10:56:47 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Tue Dec 29 10:57:47 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Tue Dec 29 11:12:17 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Tue Dec 29 12:06:17 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Tue Dec 29 12:26:47 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Tue Dec 29 12:27:47 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Tue Dec 29 13:46:17 2009
>
>   WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
>
>   Wed Dec 30 10:02:16 2009`
>   >>> WAITED TOO LONG FOR A ROW CACHE ENQUEUE LOCK! pid=37
>   System State dumped to trace file [snip]\udump\ora_2860.trc
>   Wed Dec 30 11:55:59 2009
>   orakill: attempting to kill tid=436
>   Wed Dec 30 11:56:04 2009
>   orakill: ssthreadkill(tid=436) unable to get the thread list mutex: err=0

**Resolution**: It seems like this is a 10.2.0.3 bug and I need to restart the instance, which I do not have permission to do, so I will have wait a few days.

Comment: What version of the database is this? The orakill message at the end is seen in 10.2.0.3 and is a bug.

Comment: Look in udump\ora_2860.trc for messages pertaining to the enqueue lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select s.username, s.sid, p.spid 
  from v$session s join v$process p on addr=paddr
where s.username = 'USER2';
```

Using the spid value from the above query, log on to the server and issue the following command from a DOS command prompt:

```
orakill YOURSID spid
```

YOURSID is the SID of the database instance you're dealing with.

orakill often works when the GUI tools fail to kill processes.  Here is a [nice overview of orakill](http://www.oracleutilities.com/OSUtil/orakill.html).  Note reason #1 for using orakill - it might explain why you can't use your GUI tool:

> The alter system statement will not
>   clear any locks that exist.  Instead,
>   the session will remain connected
>   until it times out, then the session
>   is killed and the locks are released. 
>   The orakill command will kill the
>   thread and the locks instantly.

**Update:**

You can also try:

```
select sid, serial#, program from v$session;
alter system kill session '<SID>,<SERIAL#>' immediate;
```

although I wouldn't hold out a lot of hope...

Comment: I ran orakill and it returned "Kill of thread id 436 in instance [MYSID] successfully signalled." but I'm still seeing all 11 rows being returned by the query against v$session and v$process.

Comment: I assume you tried to kill the oldest session. Is there anything of interest in the alert log?  From an SQL*Plus prompt, run "show parameter background_dump_dest", which will tell you where on the server the directory where the alert log is kept.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions! I updated the question with a snippet from the bottom of the alert log. I don't see anything interesting over the past two months until what I posted started this week. There were more 'orakill: attempting to kill tid=' lines after the end of this snippet that I left out for brevity.

Comment: If this is 10.2.0.x, x < 4, you may have to restart the instance to free this user account up.

Comment: I checked v$version and indeed this is 10.2.0.3.0.

Comment: The 'alter system kill session' command did not work, so it looks like I'll need to wait a few days to restart the instance since I can't restart it now. Thanks for your help DCookie!

Comment: Most welcome. You probably want to get current with patches!